# Bootstrap Tool Tips in a panel then in btn-group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm a total newb when it comes to Bootstrap, but for some reason I cant get the below tool tip that is inside a panel then inside btn-group to work.

The documentation here 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-examples

Talks about...

"Tooltips in button groups and input groups require special setting
When using tooltips on elements within a .btn-group or an .input-group, you'll have to specify the option container: 'body' (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is triggered)."

But I have no idea what that means!

I've tried including tooltip.js but that doesn't seem to do anything to help me.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
  <div class="panel panel-default hidden-xs">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                                <h4> Welcome</h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 text-right">

                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></span></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just to avoid unwanted behavior. If you don't specify the container the tooltip might just be cutoff or other have weird behavior. Here is an example using your code:

http://www.bootply.com/115182

You just have to make sure you include the jQuery part of the code and you should be golden.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tooltip1').tooltip();
        });
```

I also added the `data-container` and an `id` to your html.

```
<button type="button" id="tooltip1" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```